# Unable to autowire dozer Mapper in component class in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, dozer

I am new to *Spring Boot*. I was trying to develop small application in *spring boot* mvc with *neo4j* database. Following is my *Server*

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "myproject" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "myproject")
public class Server extends Neo4jConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner
{

public Server()
{
    setBasePackage("myproject");
}

@Bean
SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService()
{
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
}

@Bean
Mapper mapper()
{
    return new DozerBeanMapper();
}

public void run(String... args) throws Exception
{
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
}

}
```

Following is my main class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "myproject.business" })
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "myproject")
public class MainWithStructure extends Neo4jConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner
{
@Autowired
private MyService myService;

public MainWithStructure()
{
    setBasePackage("myproject");
}

@Bean
SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService()
{
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
}

.......
......
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("accessingdataneo4j.db"));

    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainWithStructure.class);
    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    app.run(args);
}

}
```

Following is my *Component* class

```
@Component
public class MyService
{

@Autowired
private Mapper mapper;  //Fails to autowire org.dozer.Mapper

.....
}
```

Following is my *Controller* class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class MyController
{
@Autowired
private Mapper mapper;  //autowire sucess org.dozer.Mapper
}
```

I got following Exception when I run main class *MainWithStructure*

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainWithStructure': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myproject.business.MyService myproject.main.MainWithStructure.MyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.dozer.Mapper myproject.business.MyService.mapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.dozer.Mapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Following is my project structure

> demo_project
>
> - src/main/java
>
> ---myproject.main
>
> ------MainWithStructure.java
>
> ------Server.java
>
> ---myproject.business
>
> ------MyService.java
>
> ---myproject.rest
>
> ------MyController.java

If I autowire `org.dozer.Mapper` in *Controller*, it sucessfuly autowired it. BUT if I autowire `org.dozer.Mapper` in *Component* class it fails to autowire.
Why it is failing to autowire `org.dozer.Mapper` only on Component class?

Please make me correct if I wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Is Spring trying and failing to create an instance of MyService, or not trying to create one at all? Can you update the question with the error? Also, what packages are you various classes in? They'll all need to be in a package called myproject or a sub-package of it.

Comment: Got it from one of your past post answer ;). Just wrote @ComponentScan instead of @ComponentScan({ "myproject.business" }) on MainWithStructire class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Server` is not in one of the packages that you `@ComponentScan`, so the `Mapper` is indeed not a bean. Try removing the explicit package from the `@ComponentScan` (since everything is in a subpackage of the main class that will pick up all the components).

Answer (score 1):

You can add @SpringBootApplication in your main class which has @ComponentScan
which will scan all your sub components in project.